# How do you make the line break without using a line break or paragraph tag?

Tags: html

With line break:

```
<p>
  <b><u>
  Procedure
  </u></b>
  <br>
  Procedure will
</p>
```

Display:

**Procedure**
 Procedure will

Need to look like:

**Procedure**
 Procedure will

without using line break or paragraph tags

Comment: Have you tried `\n`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need this but you can create two `block`ing elements for that:

```css
div.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">Procedure</div>
<div>Procedure will</div>
```

> I used css to bold the title, but you can use `<b>` for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

```css
b{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <!--<b><u>Procedure</u></b>-->
  <b>Procedure</b>
  Procedure will
</p>
```

Comment: Seems OP doesnt want `underline`.

Comment: @MKR If you don't want `underline`, just remove `<u></u>`. I just protect original code do my best.

Comment: Yes. I know, still wanted to mention it to you so that you can match OP expectation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<pre>` tag. Something like:

```
<pre>
<b>Procedure </b>
Procedure will
</pre>
```